# kendo grid request null when update and sent type is create

Tags: php, javascript, grid, kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo UI Grid. Basically, what I want to do is bind the grid on remote data which are sent on json format and be able to edit it. 
The Grid receive the data and display it as I want. However, when I want to edit a cell, the request received in the php file is null, and the type sent is "create" while I would like it to be an "update".

Here is the code used:
-the javascript contains the grid declaration

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "testgrid.php?type=read"
            },
            update: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "testgrid.php?type=update"
            },
            create: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "testgrid.php?type=create"
            },
            destroy: {
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "testgrid.php?type=destroy"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function(result) {
                return result.Result || result.data;
            },
            model: {
                id: "bbmindex",
                fields: {
                    totalvente: {type: "number"}
                }

            },
            total: function(result) {
                return result.totalData || result.PageSize || result.length || 0;
            }
        }           
    });
    var param = {
        columns: [
            {
                field: "naturetravaux", title: "nature travaux"
            },
            {
                field: "totalvente", title: "total vente"
            }
        ],
        selectable: 'multiplerows',
        editable: true,
        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel", "destroy"],
        dataSource: dataSource
    };
    $("#grid").kendoGrid(param);
});
```

-the php script send the data to the dataSource

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$type = $_GET['type'];
$result = null;

if ($type == 'create') {
    some code 
} else if ($type == 'read') {
    some code which send the data
} else if ($type == 'update') {
    some code
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

any idea about what is wrong here?
Any help would be much appreciated,
thank you in Advance

Martin

Comment: If your server receives a create is because the `id` of the edited record is 0, null or undefined. Are you sure that you get from the server a field called `bbmindex` and is not 0?

Comment: ok, that was the point... 
put your comment as an answer if you want, I will validate!
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server receives a `create` is because the `id`of the edited record is `0`, `null` or `undefined`. Please check that you get from the server a field called `bbmindex` and is not `0`

Answer (score 0):

You expect the request to be posted as JSON however the Kendo DataSource doesn't do that by default. You need to use the [parameterMap](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) option and make it return JSON:

```
 parameterMap: function(data, type) {
    return kendo.stringify(data);
 }
```